# How do you reference a list previously created in another method and search through it?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, java.util.scanner, readfile

**So I have to read a file name that is read from the terminal.The user has to be able to search for a word and then look through a list of words that have those same characters. I plan to use the goToNext and getCurrent to read and scan through the list. But i dont know how to scan through the list i previously made in the method *loadDataBase***

```
public class GameLL <T>{

    private class ListNode{

        T data;
        ListNode link;
        public ListNode(T aData, ListNode aLink){
            data = aData;
            link = aLink;

        }
    }

        public static GameLL<String> list = new GameLL<String>();

        private ListNode head;
        private ListNode current;
        private ListNode previous;

        public Object getCurrent;

        public  GameLL() {
            head = current = previous = null;
        }

        public void add(T aData){
            ListNode newNode = new ListNode(aData, null);
                if(head == null){
                    head = current = newNode;
                    return;
                }
                ListNode temp = head;
                while (temp.link != null){
                    temp = temp.link;
                }
                temp.link = newNode;
            }

        public void print(){
            ListNode temp = head;
            while(temp != null){
                System.out.println(temp.data);
                temp = temp.link;
            }
        }
        public T getCurrent(){
            if (current == null){
                return null;
            }
            return current.data;
        }
        public void reset(){
            current = head;
            previous = null;
        }
        public void gotoNext(){
            if(current == null){
                return;
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current.link;
        }
}
```

**Below is my methods that will be called in the main method. Im struggling here! Im not crazy at coding so my code might look like dog poop sorry**

```
package Homework02.src;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class OtherMethods {
    

    public static void options() throws IOException{
        while (loopStatus.loopRunning){
            System.out.println("Enter 1 to load the video game database");
            System.out.println("Enter 2 to search the database");
            System.out.println("Enter 3 to print current results");
            System.out.println("Enter 4 to print current results to file");
            System.out.println("Enter 0 to quit");
            otherMethods.userOptionCheck();
        }
            
    }

    
    public static class LoopStatus{
        public static boolean loopRunning;
    }
    
    public static class UserInput{
        public static int menuChoice;
        public static String filePath;
    }
    
    public static class Counter{
        public static int numOfLines = 0;
    }
    
    private static class Game{
        private static String contentOnLine;
        private static String name;
        private static String console;
    }

    public static void userOptionCheck() throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        UserInput.menuChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

        switch (UserInput.menuChoice) {
            case 1:
                otherMethods.loadDataBase();
                System.out.println("\nDone Loading Data Base\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                otherMethods.searchDataBase();
                break;
            case 3:
                // TODO call method to print out the current results
                break;
            case 4:
                // TODO call method to print current results to file
                break;
            case 0:
                loopStatus.loopRunning = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You choose an invalid option... Please choose one of the five options listed.\n");
                break;
        }

    }

    public static void loadDataBase() throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please specify either the relative file path or the absolute filepath: ");

        UserInput.filePath = keyboard.nextLine();

        GameLL<String> list = new GameLL<String>();
        try {
            File inputList = new File(UserInput.filePath);
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(inputList));
            while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                counter.numOfLines++;
                Game.contentOnLine = fileReader.nextLine();
                list.add(Game.contentOnLine);
            }
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
            System.out.println("\nhey i cant find the file\n");
            fnf.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\nProgram is now exiting\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void searchDataBase(){
        GameLL<String> searchResults = new GameLL<String>();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the name of game or * for all names");
        Game.name = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the console or * for all consoles");
        Game.console = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        int found = 0;
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < counter.numOfLines;i++){
            //THIS DOESNT WORK BECAUSE I CANT REFERENCE MY PREVIOUS "list" IN MY OTHER METHOD
            if(list.getCurrent.toLowerCase().contains(Game.name)){
                System.out.println("FOUND A WORD THAT CONTAINS PART OF THE NAME");
                searchResults.add(list.getCurrent);
                found++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Could not find a word on this line");
            }
            list.gotoNext;
            searchResults.gotoNext();
        }
        System.out.println(found);
    }
    
}
```

**Here is  currently my main method!**

```
import Homework02.src.otherMethods.loopStatus;

import java.io.*;



public class FrontEndGameSearch {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to the video game database\n");
        
        loopStatus.loopRunning = true;

        while (loopStatus.loopRunning){
            otherMethods.options();
            
        }

        System.out.println("YOU ARE OUTSIDE THE LOOP");

    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing static methods with non-static methods. Add the static keyword to all methods in the class otherMethods. Btw, the java naming convention is to use PascalCase for class names: otherMethods and gameLL must be OtherMethods and GameLL.

Comment: Hi there! Yeah so i sent this earlier and managed to actually fix everything that you stated! I just edited and updated my error. and my current issue

Comment: If you want to share variables inside the OtherMethods' methods it is better if you create fields in OtherMethods, remove the static keyword, and do new OtherMethods in the main function. Otherwise you need to pass the variable between all static methods.

Comment: ahh okay i see! I was trying to have a small main method and just use methods within methods. I use to just do a huge main method and one my TAs told me i shouldnt do that so now i was just trying to have a small main.